# Why did I get a mail for this question 6 hours late?

Tags: bug, tags

6 hours ago, [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/324693/why-wont-this-execute-if-block-command-work-in-minecraft) was asked, which has the [minecraft-commands](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-commands) tag that I follow with 15 minute setting. I saw it in a review first, long before I got the mail (which was a few minutes ago).

Why didn't I get notified after at most 15 minutes? Did someone from the other 132 followers get a notification for it on time?

Comment: Now I got a mail. After 6 hours. But it's definitely set to 15 minutes.

Comment: Perhaps the negative score? It was -1 when I first checked and now it's at 0.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've got mails for questions with negative score before. Actually most have a negative score when I open them, because that tag is [full of bad questions](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12802/what-to-do-about-flood-of-low-quality-minecraft-questions).

Comment: Could as well be a temporary connection issue, especially if it happened only once. If the mail isn't sent because of that the server will try again after x <timeUnit> depending on how it's configured.

Comment: @Fabian - Could it be that the mail is sent when the question has a higher score, and by the time you open it and click through the questions are more negative?

Comment: Maybe. But I also want mails for questions with negative score. For example often people see a low-quality, but improbable question, downvote it and leave. Then I will want to get the notification so that I can help the person improving the question. Or flag it, if it's really bad. Or at least change labels, if it's MCPE or missing the "technical-issues" tag. 2/3 of my edits are tag edits, they don't really depend on the score.

Comment: And especially: The mail didn't ever get rid of the negative score, but 6 hours later, I got the mail.